# Detecting which TDBNavigator button was pressed

Tags: delphi, lazarus

How can I find out which button was pressed in `TDBNavigator` in Lazarus?

Answer (score 0):

My friend gave me an answer: Use [`OnClick` event of the `TDBNavigator`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBNavigator.OnClick) to know which button was clecked. Example:

```
procedure TForm1.DBNavigator1Click(Sender: TObject; Button: TNavigateBtn);
begin
  case Button of
    nbInsert: Showmessage('Insert was clicked');
    nbDelete: Showmessage('Delete was clicked');
    nbFirst: Showmessage('First was clicked');
  end;
end;
```